# Makefile compiling all object with no errors, but not producing executable

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am combining my code with an existing library that has C and assembly code in it. In the makefile, I'd like to compile then create an executable that should create a file and print some values there. Everything works properly and there are no errors thrown. I get all the .o files from OBJS but no exe. What am I missing?

```
CFLAGS     += -g -O3 -std=gnu99 -ggdb -Werror\
              -Wall -Wextra -Wimplicit-function-declaration \
              -Wredundant-decls  -Wstrict-prototypes -MM\
              -Wundef -Wshadow -fno-common -MD -march=native $(DEFINES)

LDFLAGS    += --static -Wl,--start-group -Wl,--end-group -L"$(OPENCM3DIR)/lib" -lm  -Wundef -Werror

all: kencrypt
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@
%.o : %.S 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@       
kencrypt: $(OBJS) encrypt.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

This is the output of make --debug

```
GNU Make 4.3
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Updating makefiles....
Updating goal targets....
 File 'all' does not exist.
   File 'kencrypt' does not exist.
  Must remake target 'kencrypt'.
  Successfully remade target file 'kencrypt'.
Must remake target 'all'.
Successfully remade target file 'all'.
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

I tried to add more flags or reduce the flags. All indentation are proper. The only time it did work was when I removed all dependencies (OBJS) and randomized the process of the library. Help!

Comment: Apart from anything else `^$` looks like a typo -- should be `$^` .

Comment: I just changed that, thanks. But does not seem to create the executable.

Comment: Please show the actual output of the `make` command (edit your question and cut and paste, with code block formatting).  Make will print the commands its running.  It should be quite straightforward, by looking at the output, to see what it's doing.

Comment: I have all the object files already and the makefile tells me that it has successfully remade target when there is no exe file. I cannot compile this in MSVC because the library has a lot of asm volatile which is incompatible.

Comment: The linker invocation command will not create an `exe` file. It will create a file called `kencrypt`, without any extension.

Comment: I tried with exe and without. But no file gets created at the end of make. Only the .o files show up if I updated one of those files, say encrypt.c.

Comment: The output you present is not consistent with the makefile you present, given that the command you say you are using is `make --debug`.  The output reports that it successfully builds target `kencrypt`, but it does not print any of the commands in that recipe.  Have you maybe engaged `.SILENT` somewhere in your makefile (and neglected to tell us)?  If so, then take that out.  It is poorly suited for use in makefile-debugging context.

Comment: @jcmvbkbc The `.exe` extension is automatically added for executables with mingw target gcc.

Comment: @ssbssa that's not what I see with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld` from debian 11, it produces the output file with the name exactly matching the one specified in the `-o` option.

Comment: The exe automatically gets added in Windows. I think the problem was with the assembly code that I was trying to include in the objects. They weren't linking properly. Everything works (I get executable and objects) once I remove them.  Do let me know if there is something extra to be done for compiling assembly in Windows!